# Any way to view or download Google Hangouts Call History?

Tags: google, google-hangouts, google-voice, voip, call-history

The Android [Google Hangouts Dialer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.hangoutsdialer) app is very limited when it comes to VoIP call history. It only shows the last 100 (approx) calls, even though Google keeps a complete history. For calls made more than 24 hours in the past, it fails to show the time of day the call was made.

Is there any way to view or download the call history for the last several months for calls made via the Android Hangouts Dialer app, including the time of day each call was made?

I don't see any way to perform this essential task in the app or the Google Hangouts web site.

If that is not possible, is there a way to download any of the call history?